# Liferay 6 :portlet:renderURL not redirecting

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 .

When i add the Portlet to the page , this page is shown first

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:renderURL var="homeurl">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/view1.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="homeurl2">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/view2.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="testUpdateURL">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/view3.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<p><a href="<%=homeurl%>" >
1. Go home
</a></p>

<p><a href="<%=homeurl2%>" >
2. Go home 2
</a></p>

<p><a href="<%=testUpdateURL%>" >
3. TestUpdate
</a></p>
```

This is view1.jsp

This is the **view1** portlet.

Similarly the other JSP Pages , view2.jsp and view3.jsp are present

But when i click on any of the hyperlik displayed , nothing is happening , the same is being shown again .

Answer (score 0):

The code is exactly it should be.

Their must be something in your controller, check it once if you are not setting jspPage param in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

just move all of your jsp pages in the DOCROOT directory  and use

```
`<portlet:renderURL var="homeurl2">
       <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/view2.jsp" />
 </portlet:renderURL>`
```

Thish is working for me I hope it will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good in liferay but I worked on same thing.
Suppose we create a simple portlet where we gave the package name suppose com.portl.asif.
Now by default our view.jsp location is /docroot/html/asif/view.jsp. So I think this is the place where we generally create other jsps. Let us assume I created another jsp say fill.jsp inside the same directory asif so its path /docroot/html/asif/view.jsp
now if you want to call that jsp by another jsp page then use the below code this work for me

```
       <portlet:renderURLvar="viewEmployeeDataURL">      <!-- to redirect to another jsp page -->
         <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/asif/second.jsp" />
       </portlet:renderURL>
```

Here second.jsp is the page where I want to navigate from my present jsp page

hope this will work for you

```
        <a href="<%=viewEmployeeDataURL%>" />
```

If you further face or the aforesaid would not work for you then please let me know

thanks
asif aftab